# I am developing a DLL using Matlab coder.I need to fill the properties and details like copyright,file version,product name etc for the created dll

Tags: c, matlab, visual-studio, dll, matlab-coder

I have a query regarding Matlab Coder .I am developing a DLL from .m files using Matlab coder(R2014a).I need to fill the properties and details like copyright,file version,product name etc.. of the created  dll file(The ones we get by right clicking onto to the icon and then proeprties and selecting details).I have tried building a DLL by using .c and .h files obtained from Matlab using Visual Studio.But it doesnt work...
Is there an alternative in Matlab Coder itself to solve the problem???

Comment: Matlab coder only generate code but doesn't compile. These metadata you are talking about will be embedded in the DLL at compile time by the compiler. If you use Visual Studio to compile you can set these information in your project properties.

Comment: Okay.We worked on it and found out the solution.We need to make variations to the Matlab coder project tool chain.We need to add the .res file developed using Visual Studio(Which contains information like version,copyright etc..) to the Shared Library linker after changing the 'Build Configuration' to 'specify'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.We worked on it and found out the solution.We need to make variations to the Matlab coder project tool chain.We need to add the .res file developed using Visual Studio(Which contains information like version,copyright etc..) to the Shared Library linker after changing the 'Build Configuration' to 'specify'